# Perl module to VBA

Tags: .net, perl, vba, dll

I have written a perl module that is used in several of my scripts.
It exports only one function (but uses more) that returns an array.
I now need to use it from VBA (that is to get the function that returns the array or the array itself).
I tried differents kinds of solutions.
I found one that works. I create a .NET dll with PerlNet from ActiveState PDK and import it under Visual Studio 2010.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16518/Quick-Introduction-to-PerlNET
http://community.activestate.com/faq/distributing-perlrt-dll-y

But it is a solution that is not free. And I unfortunatly do not have the budjet.

Does anyone have some kind of solution?

Thank you,

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather spend your time than your money, you could start your research with [perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html).  Strawberry Perl should give you all the tools you need to compile another (embedded) copy of perl.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out Strawberry Perl. I should have said that it is my employer that would rather spend my time than buy a license.